# How to implement conditional statement in where clause in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to write a query and I'm trying to figure out how to implement conditional statement in sql. Basically I want my query to check the values of a column from a list of string, if the first one exist only return values with that string, if it doesn't, check the next string and repeat the process. I want it to stop as soon as it finds a match.
for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Database
WHERE if colLetter = A // return all data with A value and don't bother checking for the next values. If A doesn't exist check for next value
else if colLetter = B // same instructions above
else if colLetter = C
...
...
```

I can't seem to wrap my head on how to implement this.

UPDATE

I tried doing this

```
SELECT (CASE 
    WHEN colLetter = 'A' AND colValue IS NOT NULL THEN colValue
    WHEN colLetter = 'B' AND colValue IS NOT NULL THEN colValue 
    WHEN colLetter = 'C' AND colValue IS NOT NULL THEN colValue
    ELSE NULL END)
```

I thought this would work but it would still display colValue for all A, B, C even NULL

Comment: `WHERE colLetter IN ('A', 'B', 'C')`?

Comment: Do you have a slightly better example of the data you're dealing with and the results you want?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: sounds like you want to check whether the string exists in _any_ row? you'd have to select a count of rows with that string. If it's >1, then run the query to get the actual rows. If not, try the same thing with the next string. You can't do that in a single WHERE clause because that operates on a row at a time. You probably need a stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, basically I have a specific column in my database that I want to check for those strings. I' am trying to implement this query on a stored procedure to be used by an application that I'm writing in c#.

Comment: Also the main query involves a bunch of joins

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you want.  This is a bit complicated, but here is one way:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by (case when colLetter = 'A' then 1
                                               when colLetter = 'B' then 2
                                               when colLetter = 'C' then 3
                                                    . . .
                                          end)
                              ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will return the first letter that matches.

Actually, you can do this more simply:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by (case when colLetter = 'A' then 1
               when colLetter = 'B' then 2
               when colLetter = 'C' then 3
               . . .
          end);
```

Comment: The column I'm checking is not actually part of my select statement so this will not work

Comment: @Newit . . . If the column is in the `FROM` clause, that doesn't matter.

Comment: I tried this and it still includes data that is not part of the case statement. I.E. if I only want to check for letters A-J, it still includes letters S or X or Z on the result.

Comment: @Newit . . . Then add a `where` clause to limit the query only to the values you care about.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you something which helps you achieve your purpose , though not in a one line query

OPTIONAL - Partition table based on collvalue if possible to improve performance for your requirement.

Actual Query-

declare @count int=(select count(*) from(
select top 1 * from TABLE where collname='A')t)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)=(select coalesce(case when @count=1 then 
N' select * from TABLE where collname=''A''' END,'select ''No Values for A'''))

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

@count= (select count(*) from(
select top 1 * from TABLE where collname='B')t)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)=(select coalesce(case when @count=1 then 
N' select * from TABLE where collname=''B''' END,'select ''No Values for B'''))

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

Hope this helps .

Answer (score -1):

Based on your requirement you will need where clause with in operator and an order by to return records matched by A, B, C in order

```
SELECT *
FROM Database
WHERE colLetter IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
ORDER BY colLetter
```

Comment: If only it was so simple. This misses the requirement "if the first one exist only return values with that string"